# MIXED_DML @testSetup TestMethod

Tags: apex, deployment, metadata-api, metadata, test-setup

So I am seeing a very weird issue. I am getting a MIXED_DML error in one of my test methods. In the @testSetup annotated method, I am indeed perform a mixed dml transaction (shame on me). However, what I am noticing, if I do a deploy to my Sandbox or Production with this same code base, I do not see the error in the actual deployment process.

Any ideas or is this a bug?

Comment: See also: [Is MIXED_DML_OPERATION in unit tests broken?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/246601/2995)

Comment: I have a case number and I'm working with support on this. Feel free to comment on my question so I can notify you with updates, if you're interested.

Comment: Appreciate it SFDCFox. Surprised I didn't see your post with this. Facing literally the same exact issue after looking at your post.